# How to mock configuration.GetSection with FakeItEasy syntax?

Tags: c#, .net, fakeiteasy

I have the following appsettings.json configuration.

```
"SettingsConfig": [
{
  "Name": "Something",
  "Node": "Something",
  "SettingName": "Something"
},
{
  "Name": "Something",
  "Node": "Something",
  "SettingName": "Something"
}]
```

I want to write UnitTest ,but the following syntax does not work.

```
_configuration = A.Fake<IConfiguration>();
A.CallTo(() => _configuration.GetSection("SettingsConfig")).Returns(new List<SettingsConfig>());
```

Error message: IConfigurationSection does not contain definition for Returns.

How IConfiguration can be mocked with FakeItEasy syntax in order to apply mock data for UnitTesting?

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing closing parenthesis `)` before `.Returns`? I'd expect that error if you had code similar to: `A.CallTo(() => _configuration.GetSection("SettingsConfig").Returns(new List<SettingsConfig>());`

Comment: Nope, the brackets are fine. You can copy-paste the code and see that they are proper.

Comment: Is this the exact error message? I get a different message: `'IReturnValueArgumentValidationConfiguration<IConfigurationSection>' does not contain a definition for 'Returns' and the best extension method overload 'ReturnValueConfigurationExtensions.Returns<List<UserQuery.SettingsConfig>>(IReturnValueConfiguration<Task<List<UserQuery.SettingsConfig>>>, List<UserQuery.SettingsConfig>)' requires a receiver of type 'IReturnValueConfiguration<Task<List<UserQuery.SettingsConfig>>>'`

Comment: I think the problem is that `GetSection` returns a `IConfigurationSection`, not a `List<SettingsConfig>`. So you can't configure the method to return `List<SettingsConfig>`, it *has* to return a `IConfigurationSection`.

Comment: But I need the List<SettingsCinfig>() to execute the business logic after that or it will stay null

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First, you should implement method that reads from file, which exists in the projects of unit test. So, if there is no file .json that you can read from you won;t be able to GetSection at all. So add file there then apply:

```
private IConfiguration ApplyConfiguration()
    {
        var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("settingsConfig.json");
        var config = configurationBuilder.Build();

        config.GetSection("settingsConfig").Get<List<SettingsConfig>>();

        return config;
    }
```

Then in your business logic add:

```
var config = ApplyConfiguration();
```

You will see that config contains all the configuration there, so no need to call OnCall .Returns() at all.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP wants to mock `IConfiguration`, not create a real configuration.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the return value of `IConfiguration.GetSection()`, you'll see that it expects to return an `IConfigurationSection`. That's the first issue here.

Beyond that, in order to pull out your List from the config, you would need to do something like

```csharp
_configuration.GetSection("SettingsConfig").Get<List<SettingsConfig>>();
```

Unfortunately, the `.Get<>` method on an `IConfigurationSection` is an **extension method**, which cannot be faked by FakeItEasy. You will get the following error:

`The current proxy generator can not intercept the method Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder.Get... - Extension methods can not be intercepted since they're static.`

You'll need to put another interface in front of the `IConfiguration` that wraps the extension method if you need to test it.

Otherwise to fake your configuration file, you could do something like the following:

```csharp
var fakeConfigSection = A.Fake<IConfigurationSection>();
A.CallTo(() => fakeConfigSection["Name"])
    .Returns("MyFakedConfigValue");

var fakeConfig = A.Fake<IConfiguration>();
A.CallTo(() => fakeConfig.GetSection("SettingsConfig"))
    .Returns(fakeConfigSection);
```